# video playback Issue using Cameraview

Tags: android, video, playback, recording

I am capturing a video using Cameraview, once the recording is finished, the app will playback the video in fullscreen. However after I record the first video, I am only seeing a black screen. If I ress back and record another video everything works and the playback is successful. The errors I am having are:

> E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>   E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR

here is the code sample:

public class VideoPreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
FullscreenVideoLayout videoLayout;
CustomReusingDialog mCustomReusingDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_preview);
    videoLayout = (FullscreenVideoLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    videoLayout.setActivity(this);
    final Uri videoUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("video");
    try {
        videoLayout.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    videoLayout.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            playVideo();
        }
    });

    videoLayout.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mCustomReusingDialog =CustomReusingDialog.newInstance(new CustomReusingDialog.Builder(VideoPreviewActivity.this, new CustomReusingDialog.OnDialogShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGetDialog(final Dialog mDialog, View mView) {
                    TextView uploadText =(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.uploadText);
                    TextView deleteText =(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.deleteText);

                    uploadText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                            mCustomReusingDialog.dismiss();
                            if (LoginManager.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
                            new UploadManager(VideoPreviewActivity.this,new File(videoUri.getPath())).execute();
                            else
                                LoginManager.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"Please Check your Network Settings!!");
                        }
                    });

                    deleteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            mCustomReusingDialog.dismiss();
                            UploadManager.deleteFile(VideoPreviewActivity.this,new File(videoUri.getPath()));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).setDialogLayout(R.layout.dialog_upload).setCancelAble(true));
            mCustomReusingDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
        }
    });
}

void playVideo() {
    if (videoLayout.isPlaying()) return;
    videoLayout.start();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}
}}
```